# Accesing configuration file in PHP fails

Tags: php

Well, I have a code where I access to a .php file (the one containing the database connection data). The problem is that when I try to do it in a function included, it doesn't allow me to do.

I have these two codes in the index.php file:

This one is not working, saying: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\giveaways\includes\user.php on line 43

```
require 'includes/user.php';
$user->GetUnreadMessages($_COOKIE['userID']);
```

And the user.php class, containing the method:

```
public function GetUnreadMessages()
{
    require('config.php');
    $connectionHandle = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    ...
}
```

In the other hand, this code works perfectly:

```
require('includes/config.php');
$connectionHandle = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
```

To finish with this, I have to say that only happens when I run it on XAMPP, not when I upload to the webhost.

Comment: If the file is not loading, `require` should return a warning too...

Comment: What you describe is a perfectly explainable and expected operation. I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: is the file with the function been included into a page at root level? if so you need the path from the root level to the script

Comment: What does `__DIR__` result to in both files?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
public function GetUnreadMessages()
{
    require('config.php');
    $connectionHandle = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    ...
}
```

to:

```
public function GetUnreadMessages()
{
    require('includes/config.php');
    $connectionHandle = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    ...
}
```

Comment: TS states user.php is in the includes directory.. The issue is with using XAMPP; as it's working on the host.

Comment: @Luceos Yah, then he shall file a bug report on XAMPP not working. Clearly it cannot be the code. Not saying my code shall solve the problem, but the guy is calling `require config.php` while being in parent folder, that might include another `config.php` file located in parent folder

Comment: the index.php file loads `require 'includes/user.php';` in which the config is loaded through `include 'config.php';`. In effect this is perfectly fine. You wouldn't need to have to add the subfolder includes, because then you're trying to include from `includes/includes/config.php`.

Comment: Let it be. I cannot see any other dodgy things he posted, except the `require` being inside of a function, which is a risky design decision.